# MySql performance

Tags: mysql

MySql DB importing process is very slow. I started at 6:00 PM and it is not completed. How to solve ?

DB size: 290 MB
MySql Server : 5.7
File system : ext4 
RAM : 16 GB

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Please also specify how you import.